# using fixedthreadpool java how to check if finished

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using an FixedThreadPool in Java to process Images. The Problem what i have is, that first of all i am parsing an xml, with the information of this xml i am starting the threads in the pool (for downloading stuff).

The Problem is now, i am filling the ThreadPool with information after every < tag > in the xml. So for the start i dont know how many times i will have to add threads to the pool. for example:

xml:

```
<object>
<download></download>
<download></download>
<download></download>
</object>

<object>
<download></download>
<download></download>
</object>
```

I am creating an ArrayList with the download Information, and than pass it to the threadpool.

The Threadpool looks like this:

```
    public void addAnhang(ArrayList<Anhang> a, String intern_id){

    this.generateFolder(intern_id);


    for(Anhang anh:a){
        anh.setZielordner(props.getProperty("zielordner_anhang")+intern_id+File.separator);

        this.tasks.add(Executors.callable(new AnhangWorker(anh)));
        //this.pool.execute(new AnhangWorker(anh));
    }

    try {
        this.pool.invokeAll(tasks);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("end of this cycle");
}
```

So now my question. HOW do i know when all of my threads are finished? The xml parser is faster than the downloads, so i cant kill all threads after the xml is finished. But i dont know when the threadpool is done with downloading all files.

Comment: ok, but which parameters do i need in awaitTermination (it could be that the threadpool needs 5 minutes more that the xml parser)

Comment: i tried something like this:

while(!this.poool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
System.out.println("pool still running");

But it also dont shut down after the threads finished..

Comment: That should work but no point in looping unless you need to do something in the loop.

Comment: oh... thanks. haha fail. 

while(!this.pool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.Seconds)){ System.out.println("pool still running"); this.pool.shutdown();}

this fixed it :) thanks again

Comment: I've moved my comments out to an answer so you can accept it if you want.  Also, you should call `pool.shutdown()` after you submit all of your jobs to the thread-pool and _before_ you call `awaitTermination(...)`.  You should _not_ call `shutdown()` in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

> HOW do i know when all of my threads are finished? The xml parser is faster than the downloads, so i cant kill all threads after the xml is finished. But i dont know when the threadpool is done with downloading all files.

If a `Threadpool` in your post is an `ExecutorService` then you should call `this.pool.shutdown();` on it after you have submitted all jobs to the pool.  Then you can call `this.pool.awaitTermination(...);` to wait for the tasks to finish.

If you want to wait forever then do something like `this.pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_LONG, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`.